# Install error in rhel server

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6, installation

I have a rhel machine with no internet or rhel subscrription. I loaded a rhel 6 dvd and trying to install some package from that dvd. When I am trying to install gcc I get the following error.

```
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.i686 (rhel6-Server)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.149.el6
           Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-6-server-rpms)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.192.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 (rhel6-Server)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.149.el6
```

What does that error mean? I have both 32 bit and 64 bit glibc installed on my machine

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-34 rhel]# yum list installed | grep glibc-common
glibc-common.x86_64                2.12-1.192.el6            @rhel-6-server-rpms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you installed and/or updated the server from a package source that is newer then the DVD you now try to install from.

Try to burn a newer DVD. 6.8 is the current version, but I've no idea if they include glibc 2.12-1.192 or an earlier release. If that's not working because you updated the server to an even newer state, you'll have to either connect it to the network or manually import the correct package versions of everything you need.